# Can I activate Google Maps API Geolocation onclick?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is it possible to activate the geolocation js with an onclick?

If I include the geolocation code (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation) into my maps it works fine but it initiates the code onload.

What I want to do is give the user the option to geolocate with a button. I've tried moving the relevant code into an onclick() function but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Here is my code:

```
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5146984674518, -0.0723123550415039);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 14,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
},
panControl: true,
    panControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
},
zoomControl: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
},
streetViewControl: false,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("energymap"),
    myOptions);
}

$('a#geolocate').click(function() {
// Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  // Try Google Gears Geolocation
  } else if (google.gears) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
    geo.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  } else {
    browserSupportFlag = false;
    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag == true) {
      alert("Geolocation service failed.");
      initialLocation = newyork;
    } else {
      alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation. We've placed you in Siberia.");
      initialLocation = siberia;
    }
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Try including the click event code in your $(document).ready(function() block, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a#geolocate').click(function() { 
       ....
  });
});
```

I just did some tests with your code and it worked for me once I included it in the $(document).ready handler.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been looking for a way to move from onload to button onclick and this worked beautifully.